# Windows Live ID authentication : Get User Details

Tags: c#, windows-live-id

I have implemented Windows Live ID authentication as per below link steps :

[Windows Live ID Authentication Implementation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb676633.aspx)

Is there any way to get Email ID from the response of the Service which is entered by User while logging in ?

I have referred below link but I see that we only get Name Identifier token from the response service.

[Service Response](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb676640.aspx)

**Purpose :** Once User logs in to the Application using Windows Live ID Authentication, I want to filter Menu items to be displayed on the Dashboard Based on the Role assigned to that User. So I need to check in Application Database that what kind of Role is assigned to the logged in User using Email ID.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like link provided is to an implementation that will soon be obsolete.

> This topic describes functionality that will be obsolete. This functionality is provided only to support legacy applications. Live Connect incorporates features that provide equivalent functionality.

I would recommend implementing Windows Live Authentication using the Apps 2.0 endpoints. You can register your app at https://apps.dev.microsoft.com.  Requesting email is then a matter of setting your scope to 'scope=profile+openid' in an endpoint requests.  Alternatively if you are working in JavaScript the adal.js library will retrieve the profile as part of login.